# Recursive logging from [org.apache.Kafka.clients.networkclient] for appender

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, log4j2

I have a spring boot application using log4j2 for logging and want to use Kafka appender . Mentioned all properties in right format in log4j2.xml and properties of Kafka topic ,server and groupid in application.properties
But each time I start my application am facing a error in console logs saying as below

Kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 WARN recursive logging from [org.apache.Kafka.clients.networkclient] for appender [mykafkaappendername]

Answer (score 1):

This warning means you should configure your org.apache.kafka Logger to send log events to some other Appender.

You should probably have a proper Log Appender defined and should refer from your logger with appropriate log level and additivity, something like this

```
    <logger name="com"  level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="appenderName"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="logLevel">
            <appender-ref ref="appenderName"/>
    </root>
```

Comment: Tried but still facing similar issue ..could you please share the sample steps to send log for other appender

Answer (score 0):

You can set a proper Logger for kafka so you can get rid of this warning:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="kafkaAuditAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="kafkaLogAppender"/>
        <!--stdout/stderr included for testing Oozie log4j edits-->
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="stderr"/>
    </Root>
    <!-- Do not let org.apache.kafka log to a Kafka appender on DEBUG level. That will cause recursive logging -->
    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="warn" />
</Loggers>
```

more details in [this sample code](https://github.com/alexwoolford/spring-boot-log-to-kafka-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml)